# Confused on the relationship between number of rows in a matrix and dimension of column space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question:

> Suppose that $A$ is an $n×m$ matrix of rank $4$, the nullity of $A$ is $4$, and
>   the column space of $A$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^4$. Find the dimensions of $A$.

I know how to find the number of columns ($m$), that's just $4+4 = 8$. Question is, how do I know that the number of rows is 4? I know that there are minimum of $4$ rows of $A$, all of which are linearly indep., but how do I know that there aren't $5$ or more rows?

Answer (score 1):

Because the column space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, here $n=4$.

For the column space of $A$ to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, the column space of $A$ has to be a **subset** of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Each columns must have $4$ entries. Hence we know that it has $4$ rows.

Furthermore, a subspace needs to be closed under addition and multiplication, which is satisfied by the definition of column space.

If $A$ has $5$ rows instead, the column space has to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: What does that mean? That the column space is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^4$

Comment: Edited the answer. Thanks for feedback.